# How to prevent horizontal list items from folding vertically when window is shrunk horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that takes up 80% width, however, when the screen is shrunk (horizontally), the horizontal list puts the last items a line below.

In the case of horizontal shrinkage, I want the items to either get closer to each-other or for the final list items to disappear (<- preferred option).

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #808080;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 30px 14px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "open sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">Langley</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Program</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About Lims</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">F.A.Q.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">News/Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Overflow only works when you have a fixed (or max.) height on the element.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px; /* <--- You need height to get overflow:hidden work */
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #808080;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 30px 14px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "open sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">Langley</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Program</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About Lims</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">F.A.Q.</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">News/Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">Contact Us</a></li>
       </ul>
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks! What's the logic behind the height affecting the horizontal collapsation?

Comment: If the height is unset or auto, the element will grow until all the content can fit inside.

Answer (score 0):

To make list inline rather than using `float` you can use `display` property in CSS.
Check the changes added with comments in below snippet.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  
  /* use ANY ONE of the following which suits  your requirement */
  
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  
  /* display: -webkit-box; */
  /* display: inline-flex; */
}

li {
  /* Remove float left */
  /* float: left; */
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #808080;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 30px 14px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "open sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */

li a:hover {
  color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Langley</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Program</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About Lims</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">F.A.Q.</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">News/Events</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `css` based on `media queries`. For example, your list item break point is `675px` so you can target this `screen size` and you can also target another screen size which will be next break point such as `535px`. Here is what I mean,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 675px){
  li a{ padding: 14px 10px 14px 0px; }
}
/* If the browser window is 535px or smaller */
@media only screen and (max-width: 535px){
  li a{ padding: 14px 10px 14px 0px; font-weight: 300; font-size: 10px; }
}
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/shihab_codepen/pen/XqGKaQ)

Please note that this list items only work upto 424px and will prompt to another breakpoint after 424px, you can optimize a mobile menu for this screen size.